# Triangular 2d mesh linear image deformation

Tags: image-manipulation, gimp

I'm in need of an application that would let me define a set of vertices (handles) on top of an image layer, derive a DeLaunay triangulated mesh from those handles, and allow me to reposition the handles to obtain a linearly interpolated stretched mutation of the original image. Something like what they do when [morphing](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2011_fall/Lectures/morphing.pdf), this time only without a target image.

Optimally the tool would be a GIMP plugin. The Handle transform tool, Warp tool or the N-point deformation tool do not fit for various reasons, effectively because the do not do the thing that's required here. And of course I'm asking for a free lunch.

Could the Photoshop trial do that? Instructions? I think [PhotoPlus](http://www.serif.com/appresources/HLX4/Help/en-us/PhotoPlus/Mesh_warping.htm) would do if it 1) was free and 2) allows straight lines instead of curves. I can live with the orthogonal grid instead of triangular. It seems that even [Paint Shop Pro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1d6NNOmbZI8) would suffice. Let's see if the trial can do that, and if the grid is freely definable. Oh, here it is, as a command line tool: [Imagemagick's Meshwarp](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/meshwarp/index.php). Now, if somebody had embedded this into GIMP...

Comment: No need for all the E’s; just add clarifications as you encounter them. If you have an answer, it should go in the Answer box.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with [Fred's Imagemagick script Meshwarp](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/meshwarp/index.php) even though it's not WYSIWYG.